# Is This Sentence a Simple Sentence?

Tags: subordinate-clauses

"*Next, everyone should know what they are supposed to do.*"

I'm taking a class, and one of the quizzes marked the sentence above as a Simple Sentence.

As far as anyone's concerned, a Simple Sentence is by definition a sentence with one Independent Clause. A Complex Sentence is a sentence with one Independent Clause and at least one Dependent clause. An Independent Clause has a subject, a verb, and can stand on it's own as a sentence. A Dependent Clause has a subject, a verb, and can't stand on it's own.

As far as I'm concerned, the sentence above is Complex, not simple. It seems like it has a Dependent Clause- "*what they are supposed to do*". Is that clause NOT a dependent clause? It has a subject (they), verb (are supposed), and can't stand on its own. I'm getting really confused now, and I want to make sure I properly understand this concept. Thanks!

Comment: You are quite right--*what they are supposed to do* is a dependent clause. Specifically, it is a 'fused relative clause' or 'free relative clause' acting as Direct Object of *know*.

Comment: It is a complex sentence, but I disagree with the analysis suggested in the previous message. "What they are supposed to do" is not a fused relative clause (it doesn't mean "Everyone should know the thing they are supposed to do") but an interrogative complement clause where the meaning of the sentence is "Next, everyone should know the answer to the question 'What are they supposed to do?"'

Comment: What semantic difference exists betweeen "whatever task or tasks that they are supposed to do" and "the answer to 'what are they supposed to do?'"